# Объясните принцип работы с бд android

Tags: android, sql, база-данных, sqlite

У меня есть приложение для работы с микроконтроллером, после того как с приложения мы посылаем команду мы получаем ответ в котором содержатся определенные показатели, например возьмем температуру на улице. После получения данных с микроконтроллера я хочу сделать что-то типа истории, в которой будет динамика изменений температуры, что-бы человек мог при желании нажать на кнопку и у него выводило табличку или список со всеми показателями которые были зафиксированы и отправлены на этот телефон, и что-бы человек мог очистить историю что-бы начать замеры заново. Я еще размышляю как лучше сделать - с локальной бд, или выгружать в облако, но больше всего склоняюсь к локальной бд так как с ней проблем будет меньше и сделать я думаю будет проще. Так вот кому не сложно объясните мне что и как будет происходить. Просто мне например не сильно понятно, как будет создаваться бд, мне нужно зашить в инсталлятор пустую бд или при нажатии на кнопку будет создавать пустая бд, и еще много мелких вопросов.

Comment: уроки, начиная с 5-го [смотрите](https://startandroid.ru/ru/courses/architecture-components.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если говорить про БД и отправку в приложении - посмотрите на Room (это рекомендуемый способ в 2018 для работы с данными).

Описываете классы для работы: Entity, DAO, Database
https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room/

Стартуете сервис, который собирает данные  в них и пытается отправить, например через Retrofit в соответствии с протоколом на сервере

Если ответить более обще, то что вы делаете уже имеет открытые протоколы как на клиенте так и на сервере - ключевые слова IOT + MQTT - например посмотрите на eclipse решения  - paho + mosquitto
https://github.com/eclipse/paho.mqtt.android и 
http://mosquitto.org/